# Quickfix List doesn't work when using ack or The Silver Searcher

Tags: vim, ack

I'm new to Vim and am trying to figure out project-wide searching. Following [*Practical Vim*](http://pragprog.com/book/dnvim/practical-vim) and a [Thoughbot post](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/faster-grepping-in-vim), I've tried using ack instead of grep and then The Silver Searcher instead of ack by putting this in my vimrc

When trying to use ack (following *Practical Vim*):

`set grepprg=ack\ --nogroup\ $* "Use ack instead of grep
set grepformat=%f:%l:%c:%m`

When trying to use The Silver Searcher (following Thoughtbot):

`set grepprg=ag\ --nogroup\ --nocolor
set grepformat=%f:%l:%c:%m`

In both cases when I search for something, say `:grep RSpec`, the list of results comes up. I enter `:copen` to open the Quickfix List. However, vim doesn't open the first match and when I press enter on a match in the Quickfix List it does nothing. `:cnext`, `:cprev`, etc. also do nothing. The Quickfix List also has `||` preceding each match.

When I try `:vimgrep RSpec **/*.rb` the results are displayed, I enter `:copen`, the first match is displayed in a buffer, and when I press enter on any of the other matches, they open in the buffer as expected.

Any help in figuring out how to correct this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `||` part of your description makes me think that the `grepformat` option may not be correct. Can you add a screenshot, please?

Comment: Thanks romainl. Kent's answer mentioned the same thing. Removing the line fixed the issue.

Comment: Would you please specify what the different flags you're passing to the grepprg argument are supposed to be for?  Specifically, what is $* for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove your `grepformat` setting and use the default, the default value should work with `ag` and `ack`

check the meaning of fields in `grepforamt` by `:h errorformat`, your ag/grep output doesn't follow the format you defined, so that :grep cannot parse the output.

Comment: Thanks Kent. I commented out that line and the `||` is gone from the results in the Quickfix List and the enter key now takes me to the file.

Comment: @zcrar70 Done. Thanks. New to SO as well.